# Socrata SODA API is rejecting with Max Retries Exceeded

Tags: python, socrata, soda

I am using the REST API Modular Input within Splunk to GET data.SFGov.org data via SODA API. I have an APP TOKEN. I am getting the MAX RETRIES EXCEEDED repeatedly.

Background:

I am building a proto Splunk based stream cursor for SF opendata. I have been testing a GET using the REST API MODULAR INPUT from the configuration screen itself, have not written any python code yet. Here is the ERROR.

11-30-2016 16:24:57.432 -0800 ERROR ExecProcessor - message from "python /Applications/Splunk/etc/apps/rest_ta/bin/rest.py" Exception performing request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='data.sfgov.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: [REDACTED] (Caused by : [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

I found out that by mistake, the REST API module's polling interval was set to 60 seconds and it might have caused a problem? (I changed it to ONE DAY to avoid future issues). I then got a new APP TOKEN and tried a GET. I see the get going out in the log, but the same MAX RETRIES EXCEEDED error is coming. I am using the same IP address.

I will be testing for the next few weeks. How do I fix this and gracefully avoid this again?

@chrismetcalf - just flagging you.

Answer (score 0):

`Max Retries Exceeded` is not an error message that I'd expect to see out of our API, especially if you were only making a call every 60 seconds. I think that may actually be [Splunk giving up after trying and failing to make your HTTP call too many times](https://www.google.com/search?q=splunk+max+retries+exceeded).

The error message `Caused by : [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known` makes me think that there's actually a DNS error on Splunk's side. That's the error message you usually see [when a domain name can't be resolved](https://www.google.com/search?q=nodename+nor+servname+provided%2C+or+not+known&oq=nodename+nor+servname+provided%2C+or+not+known&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=python+%22nodename+nor+servname+provided%2C+or+not+known%22).

Perhaps there's some DNS whitelisting you need to make in your Splunk environment?

Comment: Thx. Let me check the DNS bit on the Splunk side, in the meantime I DMed you the token on Twitter.

Comment: Thanks for your support on this. It was a wierd DNS issue. I stopped and restarted Splunk and it went away. The GET is working now.